# Use clingo output as clingo input

Tags: clingo

I would like to pipe the output of some clingo call into another clingo call, such that the answer set of the first one is regarded as facts to the second one. It should look a bit like this: `clingo foo.lp | clingo bar.lp`, but the output of `clingo foo.lp` contains some extra lines and the format of the answer set is not syntactically valid. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from README.md of https://github.com/potassco/asprilo-encodings/

`clingo foo.lp -V0 --out-atomf=%s. | head -n 1 | clingo - bar.lp`